# LNK2019 for inline function in static library

Tags: c++, visual-c++, lnk2019

I'm trying to use an inline function from a static lib, but I get

`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ippsExp_64f@12 referenced in function "double __cdecl IppExp(double const &)" (?IppExp@@YANABN@Z)`

Here's my code:

IppWrapper.h (project A)

```
#include <ippcore.h>
#include <ipps.h>
#include <ippvm.h>

inline double IppExp(const double& a)
{
   Ipp64f y;
   IppStatus s = ippsExp_64f(&a, &y, 1);
   return y;
}
```

main.cpp (A.lib is added)

```
#include "IppWrapper.h"

int main() 
{
   double d = IppExp(2.3);
}
```

`dumpbin /symbols` also don't receive my func. What am I missing?

Comment: It's not complaining about the inline function, but about `ippsExp_64f()`. Does the static library define that function, and are you linking to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your inline function has nothing to do with the error you get. The error is about referencing the `ippsExp_64f` function. You need to link your code against code containing this function. If it's not your code but an external library, add the `.lib` file to your linker sources.

Comment: This is an external lib. I added the directory containing all libs but forgot to link this appropriate library. Thank you very much!